# Jenkins how to manage workspace file

Tags: selenium, jenkins, screenshot

I am doing a simple screenshot compare Jenkins build.
The idea is very simple:
1, run build with "generate" parameter to generate screenshot and save in workspace.

2, run build with "compare" parameter to take screenshot and compare with the saved screenshot in above step.

To make the captured screenshot carry over to next build: I use the option of "Force polling using workspace". That works fine when build success. But, once the build failed, the workspace is clean up. And the generated screenshot in step one are lost.

Is there a better why to handle the screenshot? There is a solution to put the screenshot to separate server. But, is there a simpler way?

Comment: You're comparing two Jenkins UI screenshots of two builds of the same project? Really? I'd not call this „_simple_“. I'd rather call this ... [Gerold, let us stay polite, yes? Please. OK, you're right, Gerold.] Can you please explain exactly what differences in the screenshots you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Gerold, thanks for your reply. Not Jenkins UI screenshots. The screenshot is taken by selenium driver in the generation step. Then the screenshot is save in workspace and being carry over to the next build. The next build will run different logic, which is to take screenshot of a webpage again and compare with the saved ones pixel by pixel.

Comment: I see, I overlooked the _selenium_ tag and the question itself doesn't mention it (it could be a good idea to update it with a more verbose description what's actually done).